# Message Passing in AVL Trees

Tags: java, message

In one of my Computer Science courses we are being asked to create an AVL Tree. In the assignment description our professor says he wants us to use message passing as opposed to explicit parameters. To put it exactly, he says:

> you should use message passing (that is, implicit parameters) for your auxiliary methods, >rather than explicit parameters. So for example, the private insert method of Weiss's >Figure 4.17 should not have an explicit node argument, but instead should be a method of >the node class.

I'm not quite sure what he means, I have tried doing research on it, looking through the book and online. But haven't really been able to find anything.

Also any ideas as to what he means by auxiliary methods would be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: can you list all explicit parameters expected in insert() method? e.g. Does insert method expect root node of the tree in which the new node will be inserted?

Comment: He wasn't very specific with what he was talking about, from what I could find I think this is what he was talking about: private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t)

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit parameter which is passed to every non-static method in Java, called `this`, that represents a reference to the current object. This is probably what your prof. means.

Comment: I see, so for example if there was an instance variable "int foo" declared in the class. He would want us to access it using this.foo as opposed to bar(int a) and passing foo in?